# Android - How to turn off google now search blue popup when click on a editText

Tags: android

I have an edit text that is for entering coupon codes only. it should not offer to go out to a google search. but on Oreo flavor of android i get the following baby popup from the system when clicking on a edit text:

[image]

my edit text itself is simple:

```
<EditText
                                        android:id="@+id/et_promocode"
                                        fontPath="fonts/Medium-Extd.otf"
                                        android:layout_width="195dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                                        android:hint="@string/APPLY_PROMOCODE"
                                        android:textColorHint="#959595"
                                        android:textSize="11sp" />
```

How is this turned off for my edit text field only?

Comment: Have you looked at: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill.html Perhaps `IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_NO` or `IMPORTANT_FOR_AUTOFILL_NO_EXCLUDE_DESCENDANTS`?

Comment: how to set these flags from xml ?

Comment: this seems to work for me:  android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"  how would i do something similar for auto fill if it not a suggestion.